# how to point all nlog file targets to an additional interim path?

Tags: c#, nlog

Assume i have two loggers `A, B` which write to file targets `A, B, E` like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets async="true">
        <target name="A" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basepath}\A.log" archiveFileName="${basepath}\A.{##}.log" />
        <target name="B" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basepath}\B.log" archiveFileName="${basepath}\B{##}.log" />
        <target name="E" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basepath}\E.log" archiveFileName="${basepath}\E{##}.log" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="A" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="A"/>
        <logger name="B" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="B"/>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="E"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Now i have the requirement, for some time window during program runtime, to not only use `${basepath}` but also an `${InterimPath}`.
After the time window elapses, it should continue writing only to `${basepath}`.
How would one accomplish this?

The only complicated solution i can think of currently, is to programmatically

1. iterate through all file targets and add new targets based on these file targets with changed name, FileName and ArchiveFileName properties pointing to the new path.
2. iterate through all rules and add new rules with writeTo updated to the new targets names.
3. at some later point time to remove these targets and rules.

**Update:** Both Paths (`$basepath` and `$interimpath`) should be used for logging during the time window. After the time window only $basepath should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It is not possible for a single FileTarget to translate a single LogEvent into two file-writes at different locations. I suggest that you double-up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="InterimPath" value="${gdc:InterimPath}" />
    <variable name="InterimPathOff" value="${gdc:InterimPath:whenEmpty=Off}" />
    <targets async="true">
        <target name="A1" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basepath}\A.log" archiveFileName="${basepath}\A.{##}.log" />
        <target name="A2" xsi:type="File" fileName="${InterimPath}\A.log" archiveFileName="${interimpath}\A.{##}.log" />
        <target name="B1" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basepath}\B.log" archiveFileName="${basepath}\B{##}.log" />
        <target name="B2" xsi:type="File" fileName="${InterimPath}\B.log" archiveFileName="${interimpath}\B{##}.log" />
        <target name="E1" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basepath}\E.log" archiveFileName="${basepath}\E{##}.log" />
        <target name="E2" xsi:type="File" fileName="${InterimPath}\E.log" archiveFileName="${interimpath}\E{##}.log" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="A" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="A1"/>
        <logger name="A" minlevel="${whenEmpty:whenEmpty=${InterimPathOff}:inner=Debug" writeTo="A2"/>
        <logger name="B" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="B1"/>
        <logger name="B" minlevel="${whenEmpty:whenEmpty=${InterimPathOff}:inner=Debug" writeTo="B2"/>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="E1"/>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="${whenEmpty:whenEmpty=${InterimPathOff}:inner=Error" writeTo="E2"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then you can enable the no. 2 targets by doing this:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("InterimPath", mySpecialPath);
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

And you can disable the no. 2 targets again like this (Ex. when timer fires):

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("InterimPath", "");
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

**Old Answer**

You could do this:

```
${gdc:InterimPath:whenEmpty=${basepath}}
```

Then just have timer to clear the InterimPath variable from the GDC after timeout

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("InterimPath", mySpecialPath);
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer

Comment: I added an update to my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to get this working. I think your solutions would work. Personally I would choose one of these solutions:

#### GDC approach

This is a really simple solution. Use the Global Diagnostics Context and change the value when needed. So no need to iterate in the config.

Set the item on the initial value:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("myPath", basePath1);
```

And if needed, that, e.g. on a timer or when clicking a button, change the basepath

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("myPath", basePath2);
```

In config: `fileName="${gdc:myPath}\E.log"`

See [GDC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer)

#### Custom layout renderer approach

A bit more automated, create a custom layout renderer who returns different paths depending of the time.

Register (in `main` or `app_start`)

```
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;

LayoutRenderer.Register("myPath", () =>
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 16 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 18)
    {
        return myTempPath;
    }

    return myRegularPath;
});
```

In config: `fileName="${myPath}\E.log"`

See [How to write a custom layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer)

#### Without code approach

You could also do this without any code, but the config will get complicated and it could have a performance impact when logging with a very high load.

- Duplicate the targets with the basepath and interimPath
- Use conditions in your config, 2 rules for each target, something like this:

  ```xml
   <logger name="A" writeTo="A">
          <filters defaultAction="Ignore">
              <when condition="${date:format=h} > 16" action="Log" />
          </filters>
   </logger>
   <logger name="A" writeTo="A-interim">
          <filters defaultAction="Log">
              <when condition="${date:format=h} >= 16" action="Ignore" />
          </filters>
   </logger>
  ```

See [conditions](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Filter#conditions)

Comment: My problem is not a case of either $interimpath or $basepath but the fact that both paths must be used for logging during the time window and once the time duration is elapsed only $basepath is used.